# convert command not found when shell script is run through java

Tags: shell, imagemagick-convert

I have a shell script that performs OCR. It has an image magick convert command. The shell script is running fine when run directly but when the shell script is executed through java program, the convert command is not found. I have simplified the shell script for testing purpose. This is my shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/bin/test14.log

(
 FILE_NAME=$1;
 convert $FILE_NAME -density 6000 -resize "2000x" DENSE_$FILE_NAME;
) >& $LOGFILE
```

and this is what gets printed in the test14 log file -

```
line 7: convert: command not found
```

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: If your input $FILE_NAME refers to a PDF file or some other vector format, then you must set the density before reading the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

It means that your login shell that you use in the Terminal sets a `PATH` that includes ImageMagick and your Java program sets a `PATH` that does not.

So, start a Terminal and run:

```
which convert
```

and you will get something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert
```

That means that `convert` is in `/usr/local/bin`. So now edit your shell script and add that to you `PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

LOGFILE=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/bin/test14.log

(
 FILE_NAME=$1;
 convert $FILE_NAME -density 6000 -resize "2000x" DENSE_$FILE_NAME;
) >& $LOGFILE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. As it turned out, I had this path set in my bash_profile. I just had to reload it using source.